# How much entropy does Apple Touch ID sensor read fingerprint has?

Tags: ios, iphone, entropy, biometrics, fingerprint

Iphone uses by default 6-digit PIN that has an entropy of 19.93 bits

When iPhone processes the fingerprint, how much entropy does it have?

How long should standard passphrase be until it is as secure as touch id fingerprint?

Is there any research paper on the iphone's touch id sensor entropy?

Comment: you appear to be assuming that your fingerprints can be kept secret.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that brute force is the most likely attack against a fingerprint scanner, but have you given much thought to other attacks? Biometrics are often used not because they're more secure, but because they're more convenient.

Comment: There will not be a "research paper" on the entropy, but the iOS documentation will help figure out those details because it has to do, in part, by how many points of reference it looks for in the input.